# Which way do the Metro North doors open?

Tags: doors

[image: Photo of the door showing arrow]

Does the arrow mean that the door will open at the right (moving left), or that the door will move right as it opens (opening at the left)?

And of course the real question: how would you improve this sign to make it immediately clear?

Comment: The direction of movement is not a piece of information that users would need and hence it does not deserve a sign (like the gap thing), so it has to be an indicator for the arbitrary, unintuitive placement of the door opener. The better solution was to put that button where exiting passengers would see and recognize it instantly.

Comment: @Crissov I do not believe that there is a door open button on these trains. At least not one accessible to passengers.

Comment: In that case, I would improve the sign by removing it.

Comment: @Crissov That is a very good point.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.

I think that with this type of arrow, the left end represents the initial position and the right end the direction of the movement.
The door opens therefore from left to right.

Adding a bit of context (e.g. the door, the floor) to the arrow symbol could make it more intuitive:

[image]

However, I think that this symbol is still a bit ambiguous.

This is an alternative version I've designed: 
[image]

1. I'd suggest to add both some context and a more self-explanatory
   text.
2. I've placed the white arrow over the black door to make the
   relationship between them evident.
3. I've also improved the arrow, adding some movement to it.

I'd like to test it with some users to discover if the understanding of the door's behavior has improved with this new symbol.

Comment: The green sign looks very much like an emergency exit sign to me, to me it says "In case of emergency, don't use this door, go that way".

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to put a visual indication of a door handle - something to grasp and slide. Even if it would never be used it would be understood that the door would open there.